# How does nodejs handle multiple www-authenticate headers in a http response?

Tags: node.js, http

How does the nodejs http.IncomingMessage object handle multiple WWW-Authenticate headers in a response given that the HTTP specification supports this and that the response headers seem to be made available only through the response.headers object which is header-name : value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple `WWW-Authenticate` headers are [string-concatenated into a single `www-authenticate` property, separated by a comma + space](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.22/lib/http.js#L393-402).

For example,

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
WWW-Authenticate: foo
WWW-Authenticate: bar
```

Will result in

```
req.headers['www-authenticate'] == 'foo, bar'
```

This is in line with [RFC 2616 § 4.2](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2), which states:

> Multiple message-header fields with the same field-name MAY be present in a message if and only if the entire field-value for that header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)]. **It MUST be possible to combine the multiple header fields into one "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the semantics of the message, by appending each subsequent field-value to the first, each separated by a comma.** The order in which header fields with the same field-name are received is therefore significant to the interpretation of the combined field value, and thus a proxy MUST NOT change the order of these field values when a message is forwarded.